# BMI Calculator using Methods

Tags: c#

I am trying to write some code that calculates your BMI using a method.

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double weight,height;
    
    Console.WriteLine("pls enter your weight:");
    weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadKey());

    Console.WriteLine("pls enter you height: ");
    height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadKey());

    BMICalculator(weight, height);
    Console.ReadKey();        
}

static public void BMICalculator(double a, double b)
{
    double BMI = a / (b * b);
    BMI = Math.Round(BMI, 2);
    Console.WriteLine("BMI: {0} ", BMI);
}
```

I thought this would work but when I start the Console, as soon as I write one single number, it debugs this line: `Console.WriteLine("pls enter your weight: ");` and says:

> "System.ConsoleKeyInfo" can not be converted to type "System.IConvertible"

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should use `Console.ReadLine()` not `ReadKey`

Comment: yeah i just fixed that but now it debugs the next convert.toDouble line and says input string in wrong format!

Answer (score 0):

Like @juharr commented use .ReadLine() instead of .ReadKey()

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("pls enter your weight:");
    //Use a comma here "," not the dot "." : 80,4
    var weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("pls enter you height: ");
    //Same here
    var height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    BmiCalculator(weight, height);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
public static void BmiCalculator(double a, double b)
{
    double bmi = a / (b * b);
    bmi=Math.Round(bmi, 2);
    Console.WriteLine("BMI: {0} ", bmi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code and this one is pretty working.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double weight, height;

        Console.WriteLine("pls enter your weight:");
        weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("pls enter you height: ");
        height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        BMICalculator(weight, height);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
    static public void BMICalculator(double a, double b)
    {
        double BMI = a / (b * b);
        BMI = Math.Round(BMI, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("BMI: {0} ", BMI);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

OK I got the answer to this. I just used point instead of comma when entering my height and that caused the problem. Im just a bit blind xD. sry for wasting a bit of your time!

Comment: I think this is wrong.  This answer is in regard to handling an issue you had **after handling** the `Console.ReadKey` to `Console.ReadLine` change, which is the scope of this question.  Please accept the appropriate answer for the scope of this question.